# Detecting SMB Version in JCIFS

Tags: version, smb, jcifs

I'm currently using the jcifs-ng Java library for accessing SMB drives, and I know it supports various SMB versions. I also know how to set the minimum and maximum versions supported. But for debugging purposes, I'd like know which version is ACTUALLY in use when I obtain directory info from the server (that is, which has been negotiated between the server and my client). Does anyone know how to do this programatically?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's doable in JCIFS.
The jNQ Java library is more flexible and for sure has a solution for this need.